# Magento error after extension installation

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento, web

I have installed extension from magento connect from website and logged out but when I tried to access admin panel but now I am getting error.

"*There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1303816771146*"

when i traced error file under var/report i found following error report.

```
"a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Mage registry key "_singleton/emailattachments/observer" already exists";i:1;s:2604:"
#0 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/emai...', false)
#2 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(21770): Mage::getSingleton('emailattachment...')
#3 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#4 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(1988): Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abst...', Array)
#5 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28179): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Codnitive_Extifcon_Model_Core_Layout))
#6 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(28195): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#7 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27962): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/page_...', 'head')
#8 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27928): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#9 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(27929): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#10 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14024): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#11 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13949): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#12 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#13 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(81): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#14 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction()
#15 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18482): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#16 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18016): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20808): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/globaltrimming12/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:7:"/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}"
```

please let me know where to do changes so I can be able to login to admin panel.

Comment: please make yourself comfortable with the editing tools

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, your  magento compilation is on. Always turn compilation off before installing an extension, and of course disable cache. Find more info on compilation [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_compiler/process/index).